# Comparing successive values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to iterate though the records indicate in the below table (readingdate is the sorted and set as the index) and for each asset compare if the reading ( that is the odometer reading) is bigger in the previous row then print a message.

```
readingdate        assetnumber  reading
2004-01-29 09:53:00     51737    2006.0   
2004-02-27 13:09:00     51737    6195.0  
2004-03-30 08:24:00     51737    11194.0  
2004-04-29 10:15:00     51737    14806.0  
2004-05-27 12:15:00     51737    18273.0   
2004-06-24 10:43:00     51737    21744.0   
2004-08-03 07:31:00     51737    24591.0   
2004-08-31 14:15:00     51737    27219.0   
2004-09-28 09:33:00     51737    29845.0
```

I tried the following codebut obviously it's wrong. I waned to know how to do this using `itterrows()` or any other method.

```
for i , row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['reading'] > next(row['reading']):
        print("Wrong Odometer")
```

Comment: print it to the output. Of course I can change that but my main challenge is how to compare those values

Comment: See `df1['reading'] > df1['reading'].shift(1)`?

Comment: i tried that. but I get `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: @jax. The comment says "see", not "use". The error message should be pretty self-explanatory at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html)

```
if (df['reading'].diff(-1) > 0).any():
    print('Wrong Odometer')
```

---

#### [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)

```
if (df['reading'] > df['reading'].shift(-1)).any():
    print('Wrong Odometer')
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure, no probs.

Comment: Excellent. is there a good documentation that explains the chaining of shift and any function and all of that. I looked at pandas reference but there is not enough explanation.

Comment: What will happen at the first line?

Comment: @jax I'm not aware of any sources in the docs, but if you want to know how I learned, it was through experimentation and learning from more experienced pandas users answer questions.

Comment: @jax I don't know how much it'll help but this is the best available piece of documentation on pandas in the doc site: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: @fukanchik The first line carries out the subtraction between successive rows and compares with 0 to get a boolean mask. `.any` is used to check if any of the bools in the mask are true or not.